# How do I efficiently save the lower 64 bits of a zmm register to memory?

Tags: assembly, intrinsics, avx512

I am vectorizing a function using AVX512. This works, except for the store which requires saving the result to memory, which is just the lower 64 bit number.

```
inline square(double x) { return x * x; }

  v = in[pos];
  v0 = v - (a1 * v1 + a2 * v2 + a3 * v3 + a4 * v4);
  r = square(b0 * v0 + b1 * v1 + b2 * v2 + b3 * v3 + b4 * v4);
  out[idx] = r;
  v4 = v3;
  v3 = v2;
  v2 = v1;
  v1 = v0;
```

Where a1 to a4 and b0 to b4 are pre-calculated factors. The v0 to v4 are set to zero at first and then set to the input value as shown above. That matrix is then rotated.

After the `square()` calculation, I want to save the resulting double in the output buffer. The value is in bits [63:0] or register "r".

I tried with this intrinsic:

```
_mm512_store_epi64(out + idx, r);
```

but it wants an alignment of more than 16 bytes (it SEGV with an address which is a multiple of 16) and I need an instruction that works with an 8 bytes alignment. The resulting assembly instruction is a `vmovdqa64` like so:

> ```
> => 0x0000555555555122 <+290>: vmovdqa64 %zmm0,(%rbx,%rax,8)
> ```

Comment: Isn't this what [MOVQ](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movd:movq) does?  The page lists `_mm_cvtsi128_si64` as an intrinsic.

Comment: I can't quite find the right intrinsic to use it on a packed double type, though.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's not correct. The _mm_ instructions are "legacy" as in they use SSE and that's a terrible thing to mix with AVX (because they save the top register content between [transitions](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/avoiding-avx-sse-transition-penalties.html).)

Answer (score 4):

AVX512 introduced stupid misleading intrinsic names for no-masking *vector* stores, like `_mm512_store_epi64` for `vmovdqa64 [mem], zmm`, i.e. `_mm512_store_si512`.  Never use them, but the intrinsics guide *does* document what they do: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide

---

Cast to `__m128i` and use the normal low-element scalar intrinsics.  The asm instruction you want is `vmovq %xmm0, (%rbx,%rax,8)`

The low 128 bits of a `__m512i` is a `__m128i` so `_mm512_castsi512_si128` is free.

```
uint64_t extractlow64(__m512i v) {
    return _mm_cvtsi128_si64(_mm512_castsi512_si128(v));
}
```

[compiles to this with GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/PPz69x)

```
extractlow64(long long __vector(8)):
        vmovq   rax, xmm0
        ret                   # vzeroupper not needed: caller had to use ZMM to pass the arg
```

Similarly for `__m512d`:

```
double extractlow_double(__m512d v) {
    return _mm_cvtsd_f64(_mm512_castpd512_pd128(v));
}
```

```
extractlow_double(double __vector(8)):
        ret
     # the low element of xmm0 (retval) is already the low element of zmm0
```

Assigning the `double` result somewhere will get the compiler to emit a `vmovsd` store, if the store isn't optimized away.

Comment: Interesting because the docs [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_cvtsd_f64&expand=1788) `_mm_cvtsd_f64()` says this is a legacy SSE2 instruction and [these docs](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/avoiding-avx-sse-transition-penalties.html) say not to mix AVX with SSE... yet, looking at the instruction set reference book, the `VMOVQ` is clearly marked as `AVX`... this is complicated.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: Every legacy instruction has an AVX encoding, with a `v` at the front of the mnemonic.  The AVX encoding is listed along with the original instruction.  Also, there's probably no problem *reading* a vector register with `movq %xmm0, %rax`; only writing XMM0 with a legacy SSE instruction would be a potential problem when regs have dirty upper halves.  But anyway, there aren't new mnemonics for old instructions, compilers simply always emit the VEX / EVEX encodings when you use `-mavx` (e.g. as part of `-march=skylake-avx512`).